# image issue on android

Tags: android

I am downloading image from url and set to Imageview.but sometime the bitmap returns null?
why this happened?..
My code is

```
Bitmap bm = null;
URL myFileUrl =null;          
    try 
    {
         myFileUrl= new URL(url);
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e) 
    {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try 
    {
         HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection)myFileUrl.openConnection();
         conn.setDoInput(true);
         conn.connect();
         int length = conn.getContentLength();
         InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
         bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bm;
```

Comment: Do either of those exceptions get thrown? If one does, can you post the stack trace and/or what the exception type and message are. Its probably either your Url is malformed or some kind of IO exception that gets thrown and you 'handle' it by doing nothing.

Comment: Can u check ur Logcat, to ensure that , you are this Error Skia Decoder, Returns False.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you try something working already instead of doing that code yourself.
Check droid-fu's [WebImageView](http://brainflush.wordpress.com/2009/11/23/droid-fu-part-2-webimageview-and-webgalleryadapter/).

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that you get the image data from the network.
2. Make sure that BitmapFactory.decodeStream() does not return null (wrong image data).

A tip:
Run network code from the background thread. Use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).